# Массив из 11 случайных целых чисел из отрезка [-1;1], выведите массив на экран в строку

Tags: java

Не могу понять где ошибка, подскажите пожалуйста

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int am=0, a0=0, a1=0;
        int[] Mas = new int[11];
        for(int i=0; i<Mas.length; i++){
            Mas[i]=(Math.random()*3)-1;
            System.out.print(Mas[a]+" ");

            if(Mas[i]< 0)am++;
            if(Mas[i]==0)a0++;
            if(Mas[i]>0)a1++;

            if(i==Mas.length-1){
                if(am>a0&am>a1)
                    System.out.println("Чаще всего встречается -1");
                if(a0>am&a0>a1)
                    System.out.println("Чаще всего встречается 0");
                if(a1>am&a1>a0)
                    System.out.println("Чаще всего встречается 1");
            }
        }      
     }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: какая ошибка - мы должны угадать?

Comment: Извините забыл загрузить, вот загрузил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод [Math.random()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()) возвращает число типа `double`. Чтобы присвоить его целочисленной переменной, нужно привести к типу `int`:

```
Mas[i] = (int) (Math.random()*3 - 1);
```

Тогда дробная часть просто отбросится и в массив запишется случайное целое число из отрезка [-1; 1]

Comment: Спасибо заработало!